# Complicated irregular pivot in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have two tables:

```
a (column1, column2, column3)
b (column6, column7, column8)
```

`a.column1` is foreign key as in `b.column6`.

One row from `table a` sometimes matches 3 rows in `table b`, sometimes 5, sometimes 1.... no definite count of returned rows.

I have a business requirement to flip all corresponding columns in table b into one row.. like this:

```
a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8
a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column7, b.column8
a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8
a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8b.column7, b.column8, b.column7, b.column8
```

You see , the number of columns in each row from Table a is always 3... but from table b, you might have a variable number of columns.... And column7 and column8 have to repeated appear in that order.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: A SQL query has to have a fixed number of pre-defined columns.  Do you want the values in a single column?  If not, what are the names of the new columns and why don't you show NULL values for them in your example?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are going to need to unpivot and then pivot the data. If you have an unknown number of values you will have to use dynamic SQL but I would first suggest writing a hard-code or static version of the query first, then convert it to dynamic SQL.

The process to unpivot the data is going to take your multiple columns in `tableB` and convert it into multiple rows.  Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot the data:

```
select column1, column2, column3,
  col = col + '_' + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
 value
from
(
  select a.column1, a.column2, a.column3,
    b.column6, b.column7, b.column8,
    row_number() over(partition by a.column1
                      order by a.column1) seq
  from tablea a
  inner join tableb b
    on a.column1 = b.column6
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'column6', column6 union all
  select 'column7', column7 union all
  select 'column8', column8
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/073ce/7). This will give you a result similar to:

```
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |       COL | VALUE |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column6_1 |     1 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column7_1 |    18 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column8_1 |    56 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column6_2 |     1 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column7_2 |    25 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 | column8_2 |    89 |
```

As you can see you now have multiple rows that you can easily apply the pivot function to.  The PIVOT code will be:

```
select column1, column2, column3,
  column6_1, column7_1, column8_1,
  column6_2, column7_2, column8_2,
  column6_3, column7_3, column8_3
from
(
  select column1, column2, column3,
    col = col + '_' + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from
  (
    select a.column1, a.column2, a.column3,
      b.column6, b.column7, b.column8,
      row_number() over(partition by a.column1
                        order by a.column1) seq
    from tablea a
    inner join tableb b
      on a.column1 = b.column6
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'column6', column6 union all
    select 'column7', column7 union all
    select 'column8', column8
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (column6_1, column7_1, column8_1,
              column6_2, column7_2, column8_2,
              column6_3, column7_3, column8_3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/073ce/8).  Since you stated that you might have an unknown or dynamic number of entries in `tableB` you will need to use dynamic SQL.  This will generate a sql string that will be executed to get you the final result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col +'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by column6
                                                order by column6) seq
                      from tableB
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'column6', 1 union all
                      select 'column7', 2 union all
                      select 'column8', 3
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, seq
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT column1, column2, column3,' + @cols + '
            from 
            (
              select column1, column2, column3,
                col = col + ''_'' + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                value
              from
              (
                select a.column1, a.column2, a.column3,
                  b.column6, b.column7, b.column8,
                  row_number() over(partition by a.column1
                                    order by a.column1) seq
                from tablea a
                inner join tableb b
                  on a.column1 = b.column6
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select ''column6'', column6 union all
                select ''column7'', column7 union all
                select ''column8'', column8
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/073ce/6). Both versions give a result:

```
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN6_1 | COLUMN7_1 | COLUMN8_1 | COLUMN6_2 | COLUMN7_2 | COLUMN8_2 | COLUMN6_3 | COLUMN7_3 | COLUMN8_3 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 |         1 |        18 |        56 |         1 |        25 |        89 |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
|       2 |       4 |       6 |         2 |        78 |       245 |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
|       3 |       8 |       9 |         3 |        10 |        15 |         3 |        45 |       457 |         3 |        89 |        50 |
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet; it works... but can you see my "new challenge" section added to original question?

Comment: @3firelegs new challenge should be posted in a new question, please don't edit your original question with new requirements.

Comment: Thanks again... that was a dumb question anyway and I figured out how to do it... thanks so much.